# How to use GROUP BY to sum values in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to sum all values who have the same category/type and the same month they are added.
This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(IF(STRCMP(leave_type, 'SL') = 0, number_of_days, 0)) AS sl,
  SUM(IF(STRCMP(leave_type, 'VL') = 0, number_of_days, 0)) AS vl
FROM leaves
  WHERE (`status` = 'Approved')  AND `emp_id` = 'pb123'
  GROUP BY MONTH(covered_from), leave_type
```

This is the output of above code:

| Date | SL | VL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-04 | 4 | 0 |
| 2023-08-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2023-08-05 | 3 | 0 |

My desired result:

| Date | SL | VL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| July | 4 | 0 |
| August | 5 | 1 |

What condition or logic will I apply in order for that to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the source data

Comment: You cannot use "*" inside select when using group by

Comment: You probably need to replace the `*` in the select list with month(date) and remove the leave type from group by

Comment: As other said, `SELECT *` is invalid. It's purely a MySQL quirk that allows this, returning essentially random column values in the group for non-GROUP columns. This is semi-supported: The quirk is so old it can't just be removed because it would break a lot of code but the MySQL optimizer makes no effort to optimize this. Minor version upgrades have caused such queries to run multiple times slower in the past

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, I  now remove the `*` in the query and also used the answer below this question. It really helped me a lot to solve my problem. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group by `month, leave_type` you get one row per combination of `month` and `leave_type`.

You seem to want just one row per month, so your group by should only include the month...

```
SELECT
  MONTH(covered_from), 
  SUM(IF(STRCMP(leave_type, 'SL') = 0, number_of_days, 0)) AS sl, 
  SUM(IF(STRCMP(leave_type, 'VL') = 0, number_of_days, 0)) AS vl 
FROM
  leaves 
WHERE
      `status` = 'Approved'
  AND `emp_id` = 'pb123' 
GROUP BY
  MONTH(covered_from)
```